# A hex upon the one who proclaims my guilt!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

This is more of the same type of word puzzle I did in [You can order them, and keep them](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/you-can-order-them-and-keep-them).  If you solved (or saw the solution of) that puzzle, this isn't going to be as interesting because it's exactly the same thing, but it might still be enjoyable to solve the individual clues.  To recap: each clue gives TWO words, which give a letter; the letters can be combined to form two more words, which share a special property with all of the decoded clues.

1. All but what you think should be here. (6)
2. Calm them down.  Or put a bullet through them. (7)
3. Dictator's motion control. (8)
4. My armpit has sustained no damage. (8)
5. Rope off the vulture. (6)
6. Round priest. (6)
7. Your prize was going to be a sketch, but I'm going to have to redo it. (6)

Here's another one, that I got from an acidic commentator:

1. British listing of blood clots. (9)
2. Countryside grimace. (6)
3. I meant to hit the tab key. (6 or 8)
4. Silverware abuse. (7)
5. Three-legged sloth. (6)
6. Unbelieving shortstop. (7)

And here are the best of the left-over clues I came up with, but couldn't fit together into complete puzzles.  The clued letters do NOT spell anything this time, but if you've followed along this far I think you'll agree that the individual answers are pretty much self-verifying.  (Warning: some of these are rather obscure...)

- Being smooth depresses me. (6)
- Bounded cattiness. (8)
- Bruce Wayne is Chicken Little! (6)
- Falsely accused of growing crops (6 or 7) [was <s>Crop... rectangles???</s>]
- Fan hat. (6)
- Highwayman's horse protection. (7)
- Landscape coach. (7)
- Let the buyer be wearing one of my Halloween outfits! (8)
- My mental health depends on glossiness. (6)
- Platypus with a regular beat. (9)
- Quietness of the moon. (7)
- Strange burner. (7)
- The border of your pointer. (6)
- Thrown over an obstacle. (6)
- Unlucky car repairers. (9)
- Withered love goddess. (9)
- Worthy of a bevel. (5 or 7)

Comment: Can you confirm that (2) is correct?

Comment: Is this one puzzle?  Or three separate puzzles?  Or two separate puzzles and then some leftover ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First puzzle

**Solution:**

> comes from the title --
>  *A hex upon* **(accurse)** *the one who proclaims my guilt* **(accuser)**

```
All but what you think should be here. (6)
```

> except, expect

```
Calm them down. Or put a bullet through them. (7)
```

> soother, shooter

```
Dictator's motion control. (8)
```

> autocrat, actuator

```
My armpit has sustained no damage. (8)
```

> underarm, unmarred

```
Rope off the vulture. (6)
```

> cordon, condor

```
Round priest. (6)
```

> circle, cleric

```
Your prize was going to be a sketch, but I'm going to have to redo it. (6)
```

> reward, redraw

For the solution,

> first letters of first words of each pair are:  **e s a u c c r**
>  which anagram to the two solution words given.

---

### Second puzzle

**Solution:**

> Comes from the text "Here's another one, that I got from an acidic commentator":
>  *acidic* **(citric)** *commentator* **(critic)**

```
British listing of blood clots. (9)
```

> catalogue, coagulate

```
Countryside grimace. (6)
```

> rustic, rictus

```
I meant to hit the tab key. (6 or 8)
```

> intend[ed], indent[ed]

```
Silverware abuse. (7)
```

> cutlery, cruelty

```
Three-legged sloth. (6)
```

> tripod, torpid

```
Unbelieving shortstop. (7)
```

> infidel, infield

For the solution,

> first letters of first words of each pair are:  **c r i c t i**
>  which anagram to the two solution words given.

---

### Leftovers:

As OP stated in the puzzle, "The clued letters do NOT spell anything this time", so these have no overall solution.  Individual clues solved below, as before.

```
Being smooth depresses me. (6)
```

> sanded, sadden

```
Bounded cattiness. (8)
```

> finitely, felinity

```
Bruce Wayne is Chicken Little! (6)
```

> batman, bantam

```
Falsely accused of growing crops (6 or 7) [was Crop... rectangles???]
```

> with the edit, this is now:
>  framed, farmed (6)
>  framing, farming (7)
>
>  the previous clue might have been:
>  staple, plates (6) with no known (7), or
>  lentil[s], lintel[s]

```
Fan hat. (6)
```

> blower, bowler

```
Highwayman's horse protection. (7)
```

> brigand, barding

```
Landscape coach. (7)
```

> terrain, trainer

```
Let the buyer be wearing one of my Halloween outfits! (8)
```

> customer, costumer

```
My mental health depends on glossiness. (6)
```

> sanity, satiny

```
Platypus with a regular beat. (9)
```

> monotreme, metronome

```
Quietness of the moon. (7)
```

> silence, selenic

```
Strange burner. (7)
```

> bizarre, brazier

```
The border of your pointer. (6)
```

> fringe, finger

```
Thrown over an obstacle. (6)
```

> hurled, hurdle

```
Unlucky car repairers. (9)
```

> mischance, mechanics

```
Withered love goddess. (9)
```

> atrophied, Aphrodite

```
Worthy of a bevel. (5 or 7)
```

> merit[ed], miter[ed]

Comment: You ninja!  So there *are* 3 separate puzzles?

Comment: All correct except for "crop rectangles", which I'll have to admit is the one I was least happy with (I just couldn't tear myself away from the pun on "crop circles").  Let's try it as "Falsely accused of growing crops" instead.

Comment: Updated answer to fit new clue.

Answer (score 5):

1. All but what you think should be here. (6) -

   > Except/Expect
2. Calm them down. Or put a bullet through them. (7) –

   > Soother/Shooter
3. Dictator's motion control. (8)-

   > Autocrat/Actuator
4. My armpit has sustained no damage. (8) –

   > Underarm/ Unmarred
5. Rope off the vulture. (6)-

   > Cordon/Condor
6. Round priest. (6)-

   > Circle/ Cleric
7. Your prize was going to be a sketch, but I'm going to have to redo it. (6)-

   > Reward/Redraw

Final answer:

> Accurse/Accuser (Anagram of the first letters which are esauccr)

**Second puzzle:**

1. British listing of blood clots. (9) –

   > Catalogue/coagulate
2. Countryside grimace. (6) – (Thanks Rubio!)

   > Rustic/Ritcus (Earlier attempt- Slimes/Smiles)
3. I meant to hit the tab key. (6 or 8) –

   > Intend/Indent
4. Silverware abuse. (7)-

   > Cutlery/Cruelty
5. Three-legged sloth. (6)- (Thanks Mike!)

   > Tripod/Torpid
6. Unbelieving shortstop. (7) –

   > Infidel/Infield?

Final answer:

> Citric/Critic (anagram of the first letter)

**Last part**

•   Being smooth depresses me. (6) -

> Sanded/Sadden

•   Bounded cattiness. (8) - (thanks to ffao at TSL)

> Finitely/Felinity

•   Bruce Wayne is Chicken Little! (6)-

> Batman/Bantam

•   Falsely accused of growing crops (6 or 7)

> Framed/Farmed

•   Fan hat. (6) –

> Blower/Bowler

•   Highwayman's horse protection. (7)

> Brigand/barding

•   Landscape coach. (7) –

> Terrain/Trainer

•   Let the buyer be wearing one of my Halloween outfits! (8)

> Customer/Costumer

•   My mental health depends on glossiness. (6) –

> Sanity/Satiny

•   Platypus with a regular beat. (9) –

> Monotreme/Metronome

•   Quietness of the moon. (7) (Rubio points this out in TSL.)

> Silence/Selenic

•   Strange burner. (7) –

> Bizarre/Brazier

•   The border of your pointer. (6)

> fringe/finger

•   Thrown over an obstacle. (6) –

> Hurdle/Hurled

•   Unlucky car repairers. (9) –

> Mischance/Mechanics

•   Withered love goddess. (9) –

> Atrophied/Aphrodite

•   Worthy of a bevel. (5 or 7)

> Merit/Miter

Comment: Just got 4 as you commented. Thanks for No.5 @MikeQ ... duh. Yes. That's just me being stupid.

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment. For puzzle #1, the title anagram should be accurse (hence the "hex"), not accrues.

Comment: @ffao 2 was Rustic/Ritcus. So, R.

Comment: Yeah, I can't count letters.